# It prints out "works" but it does not set the label visible. Why is that?

Tags: java, swing

This is my code. It reads from the save.txt file and it gets BMG=1. It prints out works like it should have but it does not set the label visible. I run the program from another class.

```
public void openFile(){
    try{
        x=new Scanner(new File("save.txt"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not find save file!");
    }
}
public void readFile(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
        String a = x.next();
        if(a.equals("BMG=1")){
            System.out.println("works");
            bronze.setVisible(true);
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
```

Full code here. Sorry if its quite messy its just because im testing stuff out and I just add this constantly :)

```
        back.setSize(1280,800);
        back.setLocation(0,0);

        bronze.setSize(50,55);
        bronze.setLocation(10,50);
        bronze.repaint();
        silver.setSize(50,55);
        silver.setLocation(10,105);
        silver.repaint();
        gold.setSize(50,55);
        gold.setLocation(10,210);
        gold.repaint();
        timer.setSize(200,40);
        timer.setLocation(10,20);
        add(timer);
        setLayout(null);
        scorelbl.setSize(100, 20);
        scorelbl.setLocation(10, 10);
        add(bronze);
        add(silver);
        bronze.setVisible(false);
        silver.setVisible(false);
        add(scorelbl);
        Random X=new Random();
        int x=X.nextInt(1100-50)+50;
        Random Y=new Random();
        int y=Y.nextInt(650-50)+50;
        easy.setSize(100,30);
        easy.setLocation(400, 10);
        add(easy);

        scorelbl.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        timer.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        easy.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(started==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't change the difficulty of the game while its running!"
                            ,"Error: Tried Changing Difficulty while running",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                wait=4;
                }
            }
        });
        medium.setSize(100,30);
        medium.setLocation(500, 10);
        add(medium);
        medium.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(started==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't change the difficulty of the game while its running!"
                            ,"Error: Tried Changing Difficulty while running",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                wait=3;
                }
            }
        });
        hard.setSize(100,30);
        hard.setLocation(600, 10);
        add(hard);
        hard.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(started==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't change the difficulty of the game while its running!"
                            ,"Error: Tried Changing Difficulty while running",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                wait=2;
                }
            }
        });
        insane.setSize(100,30);
        insane.setLocation(700, 10);
        add(insane);
        insane.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(started==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't change the difficulty of the game while its running!"
                            ,"Error: Tried Changing Difficulty while running",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                wait=1;
                }
            }
        });
        aim.setSize(20, 20);
        aim.setLocation(x,y);
        aim.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Random X=new Random();
                int x=X.nextInt(1100-50)+50;
                Random Y=new Random();
                int y=Y.nextInt(650-50)+50;
                aim.setLocation(x, y);
                score+=1;
                scorelbl.setText("Your Score is "+score+"!");
                tm.start();
                seconds=0;
                started=true;
                if(score==2 && wait==3){
                    bronze.setVisible(true);
                }
                if(score==3 && wait==3){
                    silver.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        add(aim);
        add(back);
    }
    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x=new Scanner(new File("save.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find save file!");
        }
    }
    public void readFile(){
        while(x.hasNext()){
            String a = x.next();
            if(a.equals("BMG=1")){
                System.out.println("works");
                bronze.setVisible(true);
            }
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
    Thread thread= new Thread();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        counter--;
        timer.setText("Seconds Until Finish "+counter);
        if(counter==0){
            tm.stop();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You've finished with a score of "+score+". Press OK to exit!","Time's Up!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        seconds++;
        if(seconds==wait){
            Random X=new Random();
            int x=X.nextInt(1100-50)+50;
            Random Y=new Random();
            int y=Y.nextInt(650-50)+50;
            aim.setLocation(x, y);
            seconds=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem. We have no idea what bronze is, which API you're using (AWT? Swing? SWT? Android?), how, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
    bronze.setSize(50,55);
    bronze.setLocation(10,50);
    bronze.repaint();
    silver.setSize(50,55);
    silver.setLocation(10,105);
    silver.repaint();
    gold.setSize(50,55);
    gold.setLocation(10,210);
    gold.repaint();
```

Looks to me like you are trying to have 3 components share the same location. This will not work.

Instead what you should do is either:

1. Use a single JLabel. Then you can change the Icon to be either a bronze, silver or gold Icon. You do this by using the `setIcon(...)` method.
2. Use a Card Layout. Then you add the 3 components to the card and you use methods from the `CardLayout` to display one component at a time. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and examples.

**Also, don't use a null layout!!!**

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. When you check out the link above you can also check out the section on `Layout Managers`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in Android you have to call UI Main thread to update UI.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override                        
    public void run() {
       bronze.setVisible(true);
    }

});
```